# how can I pull data from an external json via http

Tags: json, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

//sample

```
module.factory('$data', function() {

          var data = {}; 
          data.items = [
              { 
                  title: '1 Yet Another Item Title',
                  label: '4h',
                  desc: 'Lorem ...'
              },

          ];

          return data;
 });
```

Comment: Could you give more detail ?? And a plunker example if possible

Comment: it generates a json file on a remote server , I need to read this remote json

Answer (score 1):

Try [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```
$http.get('directory/file.json').success(function(response) { 
    return response.data; 
});
```

And remember to inject $http to your factory/service

Suggested article: [Requesting JSON data with AJAX](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/requesting-json-data-with-ajax.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a factory in your controller. I'm using Firebase here.

```
app.factory('Service', function(Firebase, $firebase, APP_CONSTANTS)
{
var ref = new Firebase(APP_CONSTANTS.FIREBASE_URL);
var angularFire = $firebase(ref);

var speakers = angularFire.$child('speakers');
}
```

Where the APP_CONSTANTS.FIREBSE_URL is just the url to Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you mean, the code you want is:

```
 $json_content = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/file.json");
 $data = json_decode($json,true);
```

also see the [php.net manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for json_decode,
you can use boolean $assoc=true for your data being associative.
if you want return object of json_decode to be a simple array use json_decode($json,false) or json_decode($json).